# Equivalent of the query from mysql in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I recently wrote a website that used mysql as database and now I want to change my database to sql server but I'm having so much problem with my queries... I'd been told that mysql and sql server queries are so much alike but I can't seem to figure this one out!!!

```
SELECT 
    datos.NumEstacion, MAX(datos.Fecha), datos.NumFuncion, datos.Valor, parametros_mi.nombre AS NombreParametro, funciones_mi.Nombre AS NombreFunction
FROM 
    (datos JOIN parametros_mi ON datos.NumParametro=parametros_mi.NumParametro) JOIN funciones_mi ON datos.NumFuncion=funciones_mi.NumFuncion
WHERE
    datos.NumEstacion=1844 AND ((parametros_mi.nombre, funciones_mi.Nombre) IN (('Battery Level', 'Avg.'), ('Relative Humidity', 'Avg.'), ('Rain', 'Accu'), ('Air Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('Wind Speed', 'Avg.'), ('Wind Direction', 'Avg.'), ('Atmosferic Pressure', 'Avg.'), ('Global Radiation 1', 'Avg.'), ('Visibility', 'Ins.'), ('Snow Level', 'Avg.'), ('Present Weather', 'Ins.'), ('IRS Road Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('IRS Salt Concentration', 'Avg.'), ('IRS Freezing Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('IRS Water Film', 'Avg.'), ('IRS Road Condition', 'Ins.'), ('IRS Up Ground Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('IRS Down Ground Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('ARS Freezing Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('ARS Road Temperature', 'Avg.'), ('ARS Freezing Temperature Corrected', 'Avg.'), ('Freezing Prediction 2 Hours', 'Ins.'), ('IDI Road Condition', 'Ins.'), ('IDI Road Temperature', 'Avg.')))
GROUP BY
    datos.NumParametro, datos.NumFuncion
```

Comment: So, what do you want as output?

Comment: I have a datos table which has data for air temperature, wind and other aerology data with the time that they've been captured. but type of that data is in another tables (parametros_mi and funciones_mi) and there's a foreign key with type number to datos. I want the last value of some types that those some are specified in IN section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change

```
(parametros_mi.nombre, funciones_mi.Nombre) IN (('Battery Level', 'Avg.'), ...)
```

to

```
(parametros_mi.nombre = 'Battery Level' AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR ...
```

and you need to use aggregate functions (`MAX()`, `MIN()` etc) on columns in select list that are not part of group by or include them in group by.

Try

```
SELECT 
    MAX(datos.NumEstacion), 
    MAX(datos.Fecha), 
    datos.NumFuncion, 
    MAX(datos.Valor), 
    MAX(parametros_mi.nombre) AS NombreParametro, 
    MAX(funciones_mi.Nombre) AS NombreFunction
FROM 
    datos JOIN parametros_mi 
 ON datos.NumParametro=parametros_mi.NumParametro JOIN funciones_mi 
 ON datos.NumFuncion=funciones_mi.NumFuncion
WHERE
    datos.NumEstacion=1844 
  AND 
   ((parametros_mi.nombre = 'Battery Level' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Relative Humidity' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Rain' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Accu') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Air Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Wind Speed' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Wind Direction' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Atmosferic Pressure' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Global Radiation 1' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Visibility' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Ins.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Snow Level' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Present Weather' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Ins.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Road Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Salt Concentration' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Freezing Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Water Film' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Road Condition' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Ins.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Up Ground Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IRS Down Ground Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'ARS Freezing Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'ARS Road Temperature' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'ARS Freezing Temperature Corrected' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'Freezing Prediction 2 Hours' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Ins.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IDI Road Condition' 
     AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Ins.') OR 
    (parametros_mi.nombre = 'IDI Road Temperatu
     re' AND funciones_mi.Nombre = 'Avg.'))
GROUP BY
    datos.NumParametro, datos.NumFuncion
```

Comment: I think I have to do something with max function. It throws following error: Column 'datos.NumEstacion' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Exactly. Unlike MySql all major RDBMS doesn't allow to use columns in select that are not in group by or in some aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks It worked! But I have one more question @peterm . if I wanna use AVG, should all the select be AVG? or I should use other?

Comment: @Ehphan You're very welcome :) You can use different aggregate functions for different columns as long as they serve your purpose.